# Remove some rows from the cell array and create a new cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I want to remove the cells `(mx1)` which contain the string `Pen Drive` and empty cells `[]`.

For example: if I have a cell array:

```
S_Block = {            []
                       []
           'D\My Folder\Amazing\Pen Drive'
           'C\Go To\Where\Home'
           'H\I am\No Where\Hostel'
           'F\Somewhere\Appartment\Pen Drive'
           'Ram\North\Sky\Pen Drive'
           'L\South\Pole\Ice'
                       []
           'Go\East\Japan\Pen Drive'}
```

Then new cell array must contain:

```
Snew_Block = { 'C\Go To\Where\Home'
               'H\I am\No Where\Hostel'
               'L\South\Pole\Ice'  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Snew_Block = S_Block;      
% Removing empty contents
Snew_Block(cellfun(@isempty,Snew_Block)) = [];
% Removing the rows having the specified string
Snew_Block(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(Snew_Block,'Pen Drive'))) = [];
```

If you have R2016b then there is a new function `contains` this returns a logical value for when there is a match in the string so removing the rows with a specified strings can be written as

```
% Removing the rows having the specified string
Snew_Block(contains(Snew_Block,'Pen Drive')) = []
```

For readability this is easier than the double negative of testing for something being not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Find here ONE of many possible solutions. I have used a for-loop to check every string if it's empty or if the searched token is inside:

```
toDelete = [];
for i=1:length(S_Block)
    % check for the string if it's empty
    if isempty(S_Block{i})
        % store the index of the string
        toDelete = [toDelete i];
        continue;
    end;
    % search for the token 'Pen Drive'
    if ~isempty(strfind(S_Block{i},'Pen Drive'))
        % store the index of the string
        toDelete = [toDelete i];
    end;
end;

% delete all found strings from the cell-array
S_Block(toDelete) = [];
```

Comment: In your code, the variable `toDelete`  keeps changing its size in the  loop. Read [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) why it is not considered good